# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'pk'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I'm writing some simple unit tests for my class based views. I've completed the tests for urls in which I've used `args = ['pk']` for urls that had pks. However, when doing similar tests to views, ones with pks ends with the error `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'pk' '`.

Here's the working URL test:

```
        url = reverse('user', args=['pk'])
        self.assertEquals(resolve(url).func.__name__,
                          GetUser.as_view().__name__)
```

Class based view test that gets the error:

```
class TestViews(TestCase):    
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.single_user_url = reverse('user', args=['pk'])
    
    def test_single_user_view(self):
        
        response = self.client.get(self.single_user_url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', GetUsers.as_view(), name='users'),
    path('create/', CreateUser.as_view(), name='create-user'),
    path('user/<str:pk>/', GetUser.as_view(), name='user'),
    path('update/<str:pk>/', UpdateUser.as_view(), name='update-user'), 
]
```

Comment: share urls.py file

Comment: Eventually `'pk'` will be passed to the model for a database query, at which point it complains that the `pk` attribute/field must be a number, not the string `'pk'`…!?

Comment: Just create whatever object you need in the tests? `YourModel.objects.create(...)` should be enough (Django normally creates a separate database for testing)? No need to put placeholders for the urls since they won't work as intended anyway.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat how do I pass that object's id to the reverse function?

Comment: You're creating the object, just pass the value along... `obj = YourModel.objects.create(...)` and then `obj.pk` will give you the primary key. Perhaps you should refer to a tutorial on Python / Django...

Answer (score 0):

```
path('user/<int:pk>/', GetUser.as_view(), name='user'),
path('update/<int:pk>/', UpdateUser.as_view(), name='update-user'),
```